# Unable to run sample app second time on React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I am totally new to React Js. So I start to making the demo. I had made one demo and it successfully runs on the browser. but when I run again that same demo than it gives me below error.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. These type of questions are off-topic because you haven't added [mcve]. Currently its a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, these are often resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a version issue with some lib in your node_modules.

1. Try Deleting the node_modules folder.
2. Remove `^` symbol against all the version numbers in your package.json
3. Then run `npm i`
4. and lastly, run `npm start`